# How can I select the content of tag html with css selector?

Tags: css

I have a problem about the css selector. I want to select content of div.main-list in the pages which have not h3.subcategory-heading but not all pages.

for exemples:
page1.html:

```
<h3 class="subcategory-heading">BOOTS</div>
<p>add</p>
<span>.....</span>
.
.
<div class="main-list">list of product</div>
```

page2.html:

```
<p>add</p>
<span>.....</span>
.
.
<div class="main-list">list of product</div>
```

I want that the programme return content of div.main-list of page2.html but not div.main-list page1.html

Comment: Not in a straightforward way with this HTML. You can, e.g. set the styles for the `div.main-list` first and then reset the styles to their defaults for `h3.subcategory-heading ~ div.main-list`. But a better solution would be to change the HTML to include a new class name for the div on one of the pages.

Comment: _“I want that the programme return content”_ - what “program”? CSS does not “return content”, it selects elements. If you want to use this in some sort of web scraping environment or something like that, then please edit your question to properly describe the actual purpose.

Comment: I use css selector tester of google and use the selector in jsoup of java to return a content of div.main-list. So i want to return the content of div.main-list which have not h3.subcategory-heading, only one a selector css

Comment: @R.MYounous does your `h3` has `div.main-list` as its child?

Comment: @Aditya no it's not a child but the code is: <h3 class="subcategory-heading">BOOTS</div><p>add</p><span>.....</span><div class="main-list">list of product</div> for the page1.html

Comment: If the rest of the html is identical between page1 and page2, you might be able to use something like `body > p:first-child ~ div.main-list`, but that depends entirely on the precise layout of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Give an id or unique selector to some parent of `.main-list` on page2.html.
For eg, if you give `<body id="page2">`
Now if you want to apply the style, proceed like this:

```
#page2 .main-list {
 ...
 ...
}
```

If you want to select the elements for some manipulation by js,

```
const page2 = document.getElementById('page2');
const elements = page2.querySelectorAll('.main-list');
```

This should do the trick! Cheers!

Comment: I use the css selector tester of google plugins and I want to select div.main-list which have not h3.subcategory-heading  in this util

Answer (score -1):

I use css selector tester of google plugins and use this selector css in jsoup of java to return a content of div.main-list. So i want to return the content of div.main-list which have not h3.subcategory-heading, only one a selector css.

Comment: You should add this info as an edit to the question, not as an answer.